# Manipulating a file to add new lines

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file like this

```
a   1   5
a   1   10
a   4   15
b   23  29
b   23  35
b   35  36
c   20  50
c   20  80
```

I want to get an output in a way like this

```
a   1   5
a   1   10
a   4   15

b   23  29
b   23  35
b   35  36

c   20  50
c   20  80
```

How can I do this? I have a very big file like this and I want to split it when the first column value changes. So like it changes from a to b put a new line and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 { old = $1 } $1 != old { old = $1; $0 = "\n" $0 } 1' file.txt
```

Comment: this works, can you explain it??

Comment: What is there to explain?  `$1` is the first column, `old` the last known value of the first column.  When it changes, prepend a newline to the current line.  That's all there is to it.